# Passing variable to class constructor by inject() in java/kotlin

Tags: java, javafx, dependency-injection, kotlin, tornadofx

I have my main class set up like this:

```
class MyView : View() {    

    val controller: PollController by inject()
    etc
}
```

I want to pass in a variable (like a string for a pathfile)

```
class PollController : Controller() {

val currentData = SimpleStringProperty()
val stopped = SimpleBooleanProperty(true)

val scheduledService = object : ScheduledService<DataResult>() {
    init {
        period = Duration.seconds(1.0)
    }
    override fun createTask() : Task<DataResult> = FetchDataTask()
}

fun start() {
    scheduledService.restart()
    stopped.value = false
}

inner class FetchDataTask : Task<DataResult>() {

    override fun call() : DataResult {
        return DataResult(SimpleStringProperty(File(**path**).readText()))
    }

    override fun succeeded() {
        this@PollController.currentData.value = value.data.value // Here is the value of the test file
    }

}
```

}

[DataResult is just a SimpleStringProperty data class]

so that the functions within class PollController can refer to a pathfile. I can't figure out how the injection works; @Inject always stays red and adding constructors throws out the Controller() object return

Comment: Is the question in relation with TornadoFX? When you inject the controller, you want the `pathfile` as member in the controller as I understand. What should be the default value?

Comment: TornadoFX, yep! Let's say I want my controller variable to return a string from a file value; when I create an instance of the PollController, I want it to be given a specific path. I'll edit the original question to flesh out my code and show where I want the path. I'm trying to set up 5 PollControllers to each watch for a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for Scopes. A Scope isolates Controllers and ViewModels so that you can have different scopes with different versions of your resources. If you also add a ViewModel to hold your context, you can do something like this:

```
class MyView : View() {
    val pc1: PollController by inject(Scope(PollContext("somePath")))
    val pc2: PollController by inject(Scope(PollContext("someOtherPath")))
}
```

Now add the context object to your Controller, so that you can access it from any function within the controller instance.

```
class PollController : Controller() {
    val context : PollContext by inject()
}
```

The context object could contain both input/output variables. In this example it takes the input path as a parameter. Be aware that such a ViewModel cannot be instantiated by the framework, so you have to put one of these into the Scope manually like I showed above.

```
class PollContext(path: String) : ViewModel() {
    val pathProperty = SimpleStringProperty(path)
    var path by pathProperty

    val currentDataProperty = SimpleStringProperty()
    var currentData by currentDataProperty
}
```

Comment: Love this answer, very clear and also took into account the fact that I was passing through two variables - the path and the current data. I feel like I have a better handle on ViewModels now! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

*Main app*

```
class MyApp: App(MainView::class)
```

*MainView*

```
class MainView : View() {
    override val root = hbox {
        add(FileView("C:\\passedTestFile.txt"))
    }
}
```

*FileView*

```
class FileView(filePath: String = "C:\\test.txt") : View() {

    private val controller : FileController by inject(params = mapOf("pathFile" to filePath))

    override val root = hbox {
        label(controller.pathFile)
    }
}
```

*FileController*

```
class FileController: Controller() {
    val pathFile : String by param()
}
```

The controller acceps the path by a parameter using `by param()`, the view expects this variable by a constructor parameter and using it when injection the controller (The `inject` delegate has an optional `params` argument). The only thing left when you are using this view (in `MainView`) that you pass the file path on instance creation.

Ends up with:

[image]

However this works I would create 3 layers rather than two, the classic model-view-controller (or any derivate) layers and I would store the file path in the model.

Comment: Do not instantiate UIComponents manually. They need to be created by the framework via inject, find or add. Pass parameters with scopes or the parameter passing mechanisms available in the framework.